# Get keys pressed with Clipboard event in Javascript?

Tags: jquery, events, clipboard

I have a textarea where users can paste text from the clipboard.

The text pasted `clipboarddata.getData('text')` gets modified.

However, I need a switch that if pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> the pasted text does not get modified.

I tried to catch the shift key with keydown/keyup:

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(e) 
{
    shiftkey_down = e.shiftKey;
});
```

and then try to read the boolean variable in the paste event handler:

```
$('textarea').on('paste', function(e) 
{
    if (shiftkey_down)
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```

but the `paste` event comes after keydown and keyup. So I cannot read what key has been pressed. And `shiftkey_down` is always `false` inside the paste handler.

What would be the right way to handle this?

The only idea I got is to save the last key combination pressed inside the keydown event and then check the last one pressed inside the paste handler. But it does not seem to work either.

**Update:**

I tried to use a tiny timeout so the keydown boolean variable is not overwritten immediately:

```
var shiftkey_paste = false;

$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) 
{
    if (!shiftkey_paste)
    {
        shiftkey_paste = e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey;

        console.log('> '+shiftkey_paste);

        setTimeout( function() 
        {
            // set false again after timeout so paste event has chance to pick up a true value
            shiftkey_paste = false;
        }, 10);
    }
    
    console.log('>> ' + shiftkey_paste);
});
```

And inside the paste handler, I print the value with `console.log('>>> ' + shiftkey_paste);`.

Result:

```
> false
>> false
> true
>> true
> false
>> false
>>> false
```

Also `false` even though the timeout should have helped.

**Update 2:**

✔️ Wow, it works with a timeout of `100ms` instead of `10ms` (!)

If someone finds a better solution, please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `keydown` and `keyup` to store state of `ctrlKey` and `shiftKey`. In case of the special key combo, we cancel the event and insert text to textarea in a patchy manner.

```js
var ctrl = false
var shift = false
textarea.addEventListener('paste', function(ev) {
  var clipboardData = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData);

  var pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
  if (ctrl && shift) {
    pastedText = "*" + pastedText + "*"
    ev.preventDefault()

    // this code - i don't like it - because you can't ctrl+z
    var cursorPosition = textarea.selectionStart;
    var currentValue = textarea.value;
    var newValue = currentValue.substring(0, cursorPosition) + pastedText + currentValue.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
    textarea.value = newValue;
    textarea.selectionStart = textarea.selectionEnd = cursorPosition + pastedText.length;
  }
})

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
  ctrl = ev.ctrlKey
  shift = ev.shiftKey
})

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev) {
  ctrl = ev.ctrlKey
  shift = ev.shiftKey
})
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" style="width:100%" rows="8"></textarea>
```

Comment: This seems not to work, same as I wrote in my question. As I also wrote, the only thing that worked was setting a timeout to switch back the booleans 100ms later.

Comment: For me it works in the snippet in chrome browser. It also makes sense because the order must(?) be `keydown`, `paste`, `keyup` - if pasting using keyboard.

Comment: For me it does not work. Always the same pasted text. I think there is no guarantee for the order you mentioned.

Comment: *As I also wrote, the only thing that worked* - if the **only** thing that could ever possibly work is your own solution, then why bother asking a question?   Or at least add your own answer and accept it - don't put an answer in the question.

Comment: In any case, thank you for your help.